# Delay in performSegue

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `bar button item` that segues to next view controller.I implemented `show segue` on the bar button item, it is having delay of 2 seconds for first time and then it is normal later.

I used `DispatchQueue`  as follows but it still does the same

```
  @IBAction func addPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetail",sender: self)
        })

    }
```

This is what I have in second VC

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()

    firstBtn.layer.borderWidth = 3
    firstBtn.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor

    secondBtn.layer.borderWidth = 3
    secondBtn.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor


    do{
        let correctSoundUrl: URL = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "btnTap", ofType: "wav")!)
        self.goalsTapPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: correctSoundUrl)
        self.goalsTapPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    }
    catch{}

}
```

Comment: try with this one  DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetail",sender: self)
        }

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik , It is still having that delay

Comment: Is the second VC loading something that might be heavy? Maybe try and load the second VC in `prepareForSegue`?

Comment: where did you set the delay? Can you show us the CustomSegue?

Comment: @Idan, I did that without any luck

Comment: @BjörnRo , I did not set any delay, I am getting delay which I don't want for the first time when I pressed bar button item

Comment: ah i missunderstood. Like the answer from Moriya says, than you have big work and the next controller. Means much data handling in viewDidLoad and so

Comment: @BjörnRo I did not have this problem until I updated my Xcode to Xcode8

Comment: sounds interesting, so it depends what your doing in your next controller

Comment: I think your are missing some crucial info in your question, the func you have is not sufficient to cause the problem you described. What is going on in the second VC that could delay the loading?

Comment: Please comment existing code in viewDidLoad method of second VC and try again. This will make sure whether any operations in second VC is causing the issue.

Comment: ah you "do catch" is maybe the problem. Can you comment it out to see the difference? This party can be moved to viewDidAppear or to the background thread

Comment: yes you are all correct, I commented the code in viewDidLoad() and there is no delay, so how do I resolve this

Comment: Yes @BjörnRo is right, move it to viewDidAppear. But make sure it gets executed only once

Comment: like Moriya says, put it on `DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {`, this is better than viewDidAppear because, viewDidAppear can be called more than one time. like @RijoPayyappilly is mentioning

Comment: I moved it to viewDidAppear and it works great. Appreciate all your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DispatchQueue.main.async` here does nothing as it's already executed on the main thread if it's called from a button press.

```
@IBAction func addPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetail",sender: self)
}
```

Likely you have a problem in your `prepareForSegue` or `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear` in the next controller.

If you have some heavy operation in those functions you should perhaps try to execute them on a background thread instead.

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    //Heavy operation
    //...
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        //Potential update of UI
    }
}
```

in your case you can perhaps try to execute the audioplayerloading in the background

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    do{
        let correctSoundUrl: URL = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "btnTap", ofType: "wav")!)
        self.goalsTapPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: correctSoundUrl)
        self.goalsTapPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    }
    catch{}
}
```

Comment: I am new to iOS , can you please explain the meaning of background thread

Comment: you should show us, what the controller you like to open is supposed to do. Or what it is currently doing. Than we can tell you, if this needs to be moved to another thread. The MainThread is mainly used for interacting with your UI and stuff like data handling is cool in background

Comment: In program in general you can choose to execute a bit of code on a separate thread. This is used to handle separate parts of the code at the same time. The most common use you will see for this in Swift and for iOS is to execute an especially computation heavy part of the code "in the background". This means you let the system be responsive to the input of the user and to animate the views etc as it's meant to and when the system finds time it will execute the heavy work in the "background".

Comment: Appreciate your explanations

Comment: @Moriya , I put DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async in viewDidAppear(), but it may be called more than once, so where do I put DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async in the code ?

Comment: If you don't want it to run more than once for the controller you can put it in `viewDidLoad`